# add closing tag to HtmlElement (HtmlUnit)

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I want to convert a Htmlpage to pdf. But HtmlPage has lots of tags that haven't been closed as:

```
< hr >
< br >
```

Therefore I couldn't create Pdf. How can I close these tags by using HtmlUnit on Java. What I want is :

```
<hr />
<br />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers, I was wrong. The issue was not about these html tags. Because the htmlpage that I wanted to convert contained illegal xml characters, therefore I couldn't convert it.

I found the solution by using **XMLChar.isValid** method of Xerces library.
In addition, I had to remove all **script** and **style** tags of htmlpage with this code :

```
final DomNodeList<HtmlElement> scriptElements = html.getElementsByTagName("script");
if (!scriptElements.isEmpty()){
    for (HtmlElement scriptElement : scriptElements){   
        scriptElement.removeAllChildren();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to correct the HTML. The Java library is [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). JTidy can be configured to produce XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Actually those tags shouldn't have a closing tag. Take a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_br.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_hr.asp

Comment: Right, but they need to be empty tags in XHTML: `<hr/>`, `<br/>`